# "Remainder" operation in mod 2^32

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I debated posting this here, in the cryptography SE, or the programming SE. Obviously, I chose here, but I'm not confident in my choice...

I'm attempting to "undo" a function, but I've hit a slight snag.

I have a function  $h=x*33+c$. I know $h$, and can constrain $c$ to a range of approximately $[65,\ 120]$. Investigating all of those $c$'s is not computationally viable, the reason being that this function is often applied iteratively, so it has an exponential complexity increase. Instead, I figured I could further narrow what $c$'s I have to investigate by using the equation $y=h\mod{33}$. $y$ would be the remainder. From there, I can investigate only those values of $c$ that satisfy this equation: $y \equiv c\mod{33}$, since subtracting $c$ from $h$ must lead to a number that can be evenly divided by 33.

The problem is, all this math *was* evaluated under a 32bit computer, which means every math operation is $\mod2^{32}$. Some x's were large enough that the evaluation of the original function caused $h$ to make one (or possibly several) wraps around this modulus point, otherwise my task would be straightforward.

My question is, how can I find the remainder, given that I need to account for this "overall" modulus? I asked a related question about division around a modulus here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/250811/undoing-an-integer-wraparound# and was told about the multiplicative inverse. Does a similar thing exist for remainder operations?

For example, if we evaluate the function with values $x = 193492627$ and $c = 98$, we get $h = 2090289493$ (because h is $\mod2^{32}$). Is there an operation $\Omega$ such that $ (h\;\Omega\;33)=32$? (The result being $32$ because $98 \equiv 32 \pmod{33}$)

Here's an example of what I can do, in a case where $h$ has not wrapped.

- $h = 177676$
- $y = h\mod{33} = 4$
- Values of $c$ where $4\equiv c\mod{33}$: $70$ and $103$
- I can now pursue *only* those two values of $c$. (Find the values of $x$ that correspond to them, etc)

Here's an example of the same algorithm above, but in a case where $h$ *has* wrapped:

- $h = 2090289493$
- $y = h\mod{33} = 28$ <-- **Incorrect! Should be 32**

Here is an example of the algorithm using the operation $\Omega$ and an $h$ that has wrapped. This is what I'd like to do, but I don't know what operation $\Omega$ represents.

- $h = 2090289493$
- $y = h\ \Omega\ {33} = 32$
- Values of $c$ where $32\equiv c\mod{33}$: $65$ and $98$
- I can now pursue *only* those two values of $c$.

Comment: Write code that doesn't limit you to 32-bit-architecture integer sizes.

Comment: This question has been answered on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/250820).

Comment: @naslundx unfortunately that is not an option. The function was evaluated on a 32 bit system.

Comment: @TonyK that is my question that I referenced in this question. It deals with dividing by 33, not finding the remainder of a division by 33.

Comment: Do you know $x$? And you are trying to find $c$? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: @TonyK, I know H and I know C is within a range of 65-120. I'm therefore looking for all solutions to the equation that are integer results for both X and C. This would be trivial without the mod 2^32 imposed by the computer. Does that help?

Comment: So what's your problem? The inverse of $33$ mod $2^{32}$ is $1041204193$, as user2357112 said. So now from $h=33x+c$ you just need to compute $x=1041204193(h-c)$ using 32-bit arithmetic.

Comment: @TonyK I have edited the question **and** added a larger example at the bottom. I hope this revision communicates my intent a little more clearly.

Comment: Now that you have put it so clearly, I'm afraid you can't get what you want. For any values of $h$ and $c$, there is an $x$ such that $h=33x+c$.

Comment: @TonyK would you consider adding an answer that goes a bit more in depth? For example, why did it work for the non-wrapping case?

Comment: @Xcelled194: I don't have time right now to post an answer. But the reason it seems to work for the non-wrapping case is that it doesn't really work at all: If you don't know whether or not the computation of $h$ overflowed, you can't just assume that it didn't!